# Is chanting thikr in a circle wrong?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I went to stay with a family member last year in another city/area for Ramadaan and attended the local masjid(a shafie majid) for my fard salah. After standing in for the imaam a few times I was invited to a thikr with the jamaat. So I thought it would be good for my imaan and would please Allah, so I accepted the invitation.

I was surprised by the way they conducted this thikr. They stood in a circle holding hands putting their heads forward and backwards as a drum was being beaten and the females where watching from the back of the masjid, the men were chanting *la ilaha illah* while one member of the jamaat would jump round in the center of this circle chanting in the others faces eventually it was no longer *la ilaha illah* being chanted but a strange breathing choking sound from the throat! This went on for a few hours, I am concerned as to what this was and was it halaal? Was this pleasing to Allah and good for my imaan?

Answer (score 2):

The best example for us in matters of religion is of our prophet Muhammad (PBUH). The way he prayed, is the ONLY way that will help us come near to Allah. If these "thikr" gatherings were so useful, then our prophet must have told us the way to do that.

I would suggest to leave them alone and concentrate on Quran and Namaz.